# Compare two ranges on different sheets and if the values match copy range

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets (Current Month and Previous Month) with approx 4000 different account numbers and details in each row. The account numbers are compared and if an account number in the Current Month sheet is not in the Previous Months sheet it is highlighted in yellow. THIS PART WORKS FOR ME IN THE CODE BELOW.

The part that I cannot get to work. If the account numbers match, copy columns H to N for that matching account number from the Previous Month sheet to columns H to N in the current months sheet. I'm getting Runtime error 9 - subscript out of range, when I'm trying to define the LastRow variable but I'm also not sure if the loop below that error will work either.

Here is the code;

```
Sub RangeCompare()
'   The range Previous Month is the baseline so if the range Current Month has a value that is not in the Previous Month it is highlighted
'   If the Previous Month range has a value that is in Current Month then copy Previous Months columns H to N to Current Month columns H to N
'   ACCOUNT NUMBERS SELECTED MUST BE IN COLUMN A, IF NOT THE COPY/PASTE WILL NOT WORK!

'   Warning to the end user that column A must contain the Account Numbers or this will cause the copy part of the macro to fail
    MsgBox "!! Column A must contain the Account Numbers !!"

    Dim PrevMonth As Range, CurMonth As Range, c As Range, TempVal As Range
    Dim CurSheet As String, PrevSheet As String
    Dim LastRow1 As Long

    Set PrevMonth = Application.InputBox("Select appropriate sheet and all accounts:", Title:="Select Previous Months Accounts", Type:=8)
'    next variable needed so VBA knows what the Previous worksheet name is, this is needed for the copying section of the macro
    PrevSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    If PrevMonth Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No range selected. Ending program..."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set CurMonth = Application.InputBox("Select appropriate sheet and all accounts:", Title:="Select Current Months Accounts", Type:=8)
    ' next variable needed so VBA knows what the Current worksheet name is, this is needed for the copying section of the macro
    CurSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    LastRow2 = Selection.Rows.Count
    If CurMonth Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No range selected. Ending program..."
        Exit Sub
    End If


'   Highlight cells not in PrevMonth to yellow Colorindex = 6
'   This loop works :-)
    For Each c In CurMonth.Cells
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(PrevMonth, c.Value) = 0 Then
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next c

'    Copy columns H:N from previous month sheet to H:N in current months sheet if Account numbers match

   LastRow1 = Sheets("PrevSheet").Range("PrevMonth").Rows.Count
'  The above gives runtime error 9 - subscript out of range
'  I don't know if the loop below will work as I can't define LastRow1 due to the error above.
    For sRow = 2 To LastRow1
        TempVal = Sheets(PrevSheet).Range(sRow, "H").Range(sRow, "N")
             If Sheets("CurSheet").Cells(sRow, 1).Text = Sheets("PrevSheet").Cells(sRow, 1).Text Then
                    Sheets(CurSheet).Range(sRow, "H").Range(sRow, "N") = TempVal
             End If
    Next sRow

End Sub
```

Comment: The error you're getting "runtime error 9 - subscript out of range" on line `LastRow1 = Sheets("PrevSheet").Range("PrevMonth").Rows.Count` means that your workbook doesn't have a sheet named "PrevSheet" or that that sheet doesn't have a named range named "PrevMonth".  Double check your sheet name and named range.

Comment: It looks like instead of `Sheets("PrevSheet").Range("PrevMonth")` you might actually just want `PrevMonth`

Comment: Thanks tigeravatar, I've defined PrevSheet further up in the code as follows; "PrevSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

Comment: Right, you've defined `the worksheet variable PrevSheet` but then you simply use a string with `Sheets("PrevSheet")`.  When it's a literal string like that, you're not referencing a predefined variable, you're telling Excel to look for a worksheet *actually named* "PrevSheet"

Comment: so should i drop the "Sheets("PrevSheet") entry and just use LastRow1 = Range("PrevMonth").Rows.Count?

Comment: You should drop all of that and simply use `PrevMonth.Rows.Count` so that you're using the defined range variable `PrevMonth`.  Using `Range("PrevMonth")` is telling Excel to look for a **named range** *actually named* "PrevMonth" instead of using the defined variable.

Comment: Thanks again @tigeravatar. Sorry but its now failing on the 'If Sheets(CurSheet).Range("A" & sRow).Value = Sheets(PrevSheet).Cells("A" & sRow).Value Then' statement with the error "Runtime error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: That's because you use `Range("A" & sRow)` for one and `Cells("A" & sRow)` for the other.  They both need to be `Range` with that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Updated in order to look up the Account Numbers using `INDEX/MATCH` within VBA as the names of the worksheet names will be changing (I assume):

```
Dim PrevSheet, CurSheet As String

PrevSheet = "PrevSheet"
CurSheet = "CurSheet"

CurEnd = Sheets(CurSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
PrevEnd = Sheets(PrevSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For sRow = 2 To CurEnd
Sheets(CurSheet).Range("H" & sRow).value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("H2:H" & PrevEnd), WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets(CurSheet).Range("A" & sRow), Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("A2:A" & PrevEnd), 0))
Sheets(CurSheet).Range("I" & sRow).value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("I2:I" & PrevEnd), WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets(CurSheet).Range("A" & sRow), Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("A2:A" & PrevEnd), 0))
Sheets(CurSheet).Range("J" & sRow).value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("J2:J" & PrevEnd), WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets(CurSheet).Range("A" & sRow), Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("A2:A" & PrevEnd), 0))
Sheets(CurSheet).Range("K" & sRow).value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("K2:K" & PrevEnd), WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets(CurSheet).Range("A" & sRow), Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("A2:A" & PrevEnd), 0))
Sheets(CurSheet).Range("L" & sRow).value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("L2:L" & PrevEnd), WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets(CurSheet).Range("A" & sRow), Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("A2:A" & PrevEnd), 0))
Sheets(CurSheet).Range("M" & sRow).value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("M2:M" & PrevEnd), WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets(CurSheet).Range("A" & sRow), Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("A2:A" & PrevEnd), 0))
Sheets(CurSheet).Range("N" & sRow).value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("N2:N" & PrevEnd), WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets(CurSheet).Range("A" & sRow), Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("A2:A" & PrevEnd), 0))
Next sRow
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan but it bombs out with "Run-time error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set" on the line "TempVal = Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("H" & sRow & ":N" & sRow)" when I use the F8 button to step through the code

Comment: Apologies Jordan. I've now set the Tempval as a Variant and it now fails with "Run-time error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument on the "If Sheets(CurSheet).Range("A" & sRow).Value = Sheets(PrevSheet).Cells("A" & sRow).Value Then" statement

Comment: Sorry, the line should have been `If Sheets(CurSheet).Range("A" & sRow).Value = Sheets(PrevSheet).Range("A" & sRow).Value Then` - this has been amended in the answer now. It previously referred to `Cells("A" & sRow).Value` instead of `Range("A" & sRow).Value`

Comment: Also, this code will only work if `PrevSheet` and `CurSheet` are formatted in the same way e.g. the "Account Numbers" referred to in your question are all in the same rows on both worksheets.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, the macro now runs through without errors but nothing is copied from PrevSheet to CurSheet. Sorry to be such a pain.

Comment: It seems to be working for me, I've added in `.End(xlup)` to the `LastRow1` line; maybe try it now? It's a lot slower to copy and paste the values so in an attempt to avoid this it would be better to set the data as is done in this function.

Comment: Hi Jordan, your comment "this code will only work if PrevSheet and CurSheet are formatted in the same way e.g. the "Account Numbers" referred to in your question are all in the same rows on both worksheets". This will never be true for me as new accounts can appear in next months data and some accounts will be deleted from next months data. Since my first loop works can an ElseIf statement be put in to copy the H:N rows?

Comment: I'll update the answer if they're going to be differently formatted; try the code now.